# Windows Phone 8.1 GetVirtualizedFilesVector() equiv

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

In my Windows Phone 8.1 (Windows Runtime) app I need to create a GridView which displays photos from the phone's Pictures Library().
The problem is that when I have more than 40 photos, my app ceases due to an OutOfMemoryException().
I know that Windows 8 has a simple way of getting a virtualized files vector: 
    FileInformationFactory.GetVirtualizedFilesVector();

But on Windows Phone 8.1 this method does not exist.

So, how can I do to accomplish the same thing on Windows Phone?

Thank you.